# Please explain what "while True !=0 mean

Tags: python, while-loop

Is while True !=0: valid , if so what does it mean? Because in my program using that or "while True" (by itself) provides the same output. I can't remember why  I used it before in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works since True and int can be mixed in expressions because: "For historic reasons, bool is a subclass of int, so True is an instance of int. (Originally, Python had no bool type, and things that returned truth values returned 1 or 0. When they added bool, True and False had to be drop-in replacements for 1 and 0 as much as possible for backward compatibility, hence the subclassing.)" [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888620/comparing-boolean-and-int-using-isinstance)

Answer (score 3):

This is used to create infinite loops (or loops that exit via a `break` or `return` statement within the loop body).  The standard way to do this is:

```
while True:
    ...
```

The other version you showed, `while True != 0:`, is equivalent, but needlessly convoluted.  It works because, when treated as an integer, `True` has the value `1`, so it's equivalent to `while 1 != 0:` which, in turn, is equivalent to `while True:`, which is the most direct way to express it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `while True != 0:` is valid and it has the same meaning as `while True:` which you should use from now on.

This works because `int(True)` evaluates to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, `true != 0` => `1 != 0` is always 1 (true) .