# isinstance method for boolean not working

Tags: python

I have created a program in python which is a list of multiple data types and we are trying to sum only int types

```
a=[4,5,6,False,8,'18']

sum=0
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i,int):
        print("i=",i)
        sum+=i
        print(sum)
```

But even for False isinstance is showing True. kindly update why

Comment: Booleans are a subtype of integer. `True == 1`, `False == 0`

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888620/comparing-boolean-and-int-using-isinstance

Comment: So how can we leave boolean out and add only ints. Any suggestions @TomRon

Comment: Change the if condition to - `if isinstance(i, int) and not isinstance(i, bool)`