# PyLong_Check() wrongly detecting PyBool type?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm using [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) in my C++ program. I have a function like this one (simplified) that returns the a string with the type of a given PyObject passed as argument:

```
#include <Python.h>

static std::string getPyObjectType(PyObject* obj)
{
  if (PyLong_Check(obj))
  {
    return "long";
  }
  else if (PyFloat_Check(obj))
  {
    return "float";
  }
  else if (PyBool_Check(obj))
  {
    return "bool";
  }
  else
  {
    return "other";
  }
}
```

The problem is that is not properly detecting boolean objects. When `obj` is a boolean, it returns `"long"` instead of `"bool"`. It is like `PyLong_Check()` were wrongly return true in this case...

If I use a breakpoint in the function to check the type of the `obj` in this case seems to be right (it shows `PyBool_Type`):

[image]

What's the fail in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: [Comparing boolean and int using isinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37888620) [Why is bool a subclass of int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8169001)

Comment: That's correct; `bool` is a subclass of `int`.  There's `PyLong_CheckExact` if you really want to exclude subclasses (but that's seldom the right thing to do).

Comment: `PyLong_Check` correctly returns true when it is given a python `bool` object, since `bool` objects are `int` objects

Answer (score 0):

cheeck for bool at the top of the ladder if statements

```
#include <Python.h>

static std::string getPyObjectType(PyObject* obj)
{
  if (PyBool_Check(obj))
  {
    return "bool";
  }
  else if (PyLong_Check(obj))
  {
    return "long";
  }
  else if (PyFloat_Check(obj))
  {
    return "float";
  }
  else
  {
    return "other";
  }
}
```

Comment: it needs to happen before the `PyLong_Check`

Comment: I think change "Check for bool before checking for float" -> "Check for bool before checking for int" and adjust the code consequently will fix your post :)